# Получить сумму volume RAM в каждой комнате

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я делаю запрос, который объединяет основную таблицу `Computers` с вспомогательными `Rooms` и `Types`. Цель: **получить суммарный объем оперативной памяти компьютеров в каждой комнате.**

Пример результата:

`20 комната - 25;`

`21 комната - 31;`

`22 комната - 41`

Данные из табличек я смог получить, а вот с суммой проблема) Подскажите пожалуйста как возможно это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
select c."Model", c."Computer room", t."volume RAM"
from "Computers" as c
INNER JOIN "Rooms" as r on c."Computer room"=r."Id"
INNER JOIN "Types" as t on c."Id" = t."type";
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому-то пригодится:

```
select r."Id", SUM(t."volume RAM")
from "Computers" as c
INNER JOIN "Rooms" as r on c."Computer room"=r."Id"
INNER JOIN "Types" as t on c."Id" = t."type"
GROUP BY r."Id";
```